# How to use a spinner item

Tags: java, android, spinner

I would like to have a certain action when a specific item is selected (e.g. item 2), but have a generic action occur for any others (e.g. items 1, 3, 4).

This is my code:

```
    private String[] array_spinner = new String[4];
    private thetiki mContext;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        array_spinner[0] = "Mathimatika Genikis Paideias";
        array_spinner[1] = "Fusiki Genikis Paideias";
        array_spinner[2] = "Istoria Genikis Paideias";
        array_spinner[3] = "Viologia Genikis Paideias";

        Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                array_spinner);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        // more code
   apostoli.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                private AlertDialog show;

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

if (...) {


        if (array_spinner[2] != null) {
            //do something  

        } else if (array_spinner[0] != null || array_spinner[1] != null || array_spinner[3] != null) {

            //do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear on what you are asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_spinner[index] will never be null in this case. You've already initialized them, how could they be? You need to set up a listener to handle selections in the Spinner, something like this:

```
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(pos == 2) {
            //do specific action
        } else {
            //do generic action
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

See more information in the [Spinner tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).

Comment: i have an if session on a button.i want to use the spinner into the if of this button..so,is it possible to have on setOnItemSelectedListener into an other?

Comment: Not the way you're describing it, no. If you're wanting to Get the Selected Item Position from the Spinner, check out the Spinner docs -- the inherited methods from AdapterView, to be specific, provide a method for this. :)http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: i dont really understand it..i was thinking to use a switch method actually

Comment: You can use a switch method, but what are you going to switch on? The currently selected spinner item, right? How are you getting the selected item position?

Comment: i was thinking something like:switch (array_spinner.length) {
       
       case array_spinner[2]://do my job
        
        break;
       
       
       }

Comment: `array_spinner.length` never changes. It's always 4. You're also trying to switch on a String, as `array_spinner[2]` is a String.

Comment: yes u r right.....i dont know..i m searching the web but i cant find something for me..i believe that its a bit complicated..

Comment: It couldn't be simpler, really. Rather than searching the web, search the link I gave you. Check the inherited methods from AdapterView.

Comment: could it be easy to write me an example?i read the link you pasted but i dont know exactly how to use it..

Comment: It could be easy, but it will help you immensely in the long run to know how to navigate the documentation. It's one method under AdapterView that returns an int -- the index of the Spinner's selected item.

Comment: will it be something like the steps 5,6 from here?http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: public void setPromptId (int promptId)
?

Comment: That's under Spinner's public methods. Scroll down to the inherited methods section, you'll see one that says "From android.widget.AdapterView". You can click the arrow beside it to expand the list. Since Spinner is a subclass of AdapterView, any of the public methods of AdapterView are also applicable to Spinner.

Comment: ok!i found it!int returns the:getCount(),getFirstVisiblePosition(),getLastVisiblePosition(),getPositionForView(View view) and getSelectedItemPosition().i think that  suitable for me is the last one,right?

Comment: Yup, that's the one! Just switch on that, and in case 2, handle it however you need.

Comment: ok lets try it!!is there any way to have a common case for 0,1,3?something like case{0,1,3}??

Comment: mr kcoppock i have posted my new edit but unfortunately im getting a nullPointerExc

Comment: Just use the `default` case. Since it's for anything that's NOT 2, 2 is the only case that you'll need to handle differently.